# Connection attempt failed : Socket Exception - MongoDB TLS encryption on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, tls1.2

I am facing this error on my ubuntu 16.04 machine while trying to encrypt data from the client to the server using TLS/SSL on Mongodb:

As requested, here is my command in text format :

```
mongo --tls --tlsCAFile rootCA.pem --tlsCertificateKeyFile mongodb.pem --host 127.0.0.1:27017
```

[image]

I have created a CA certificate which I have self-signed, and created the mongodb.pem file too as it is required for tls/ssl encryption.

Does anybody know how to fix it ? If you need more info I would gladly provide them.

This is my mongodb.conf file :

```
 mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls :
       mode : requireTLS
       certificateKeyFile : /home/youssef/mongodb.pem


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

And I used this method to create a user :

```
db.createUser( { user: "accountAdmin01",
                 pwd: "password",  // Or  "<cleartext password>
                 roles: [ { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }])
```

This is the error I get from the logs :

```
"msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL support"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:34766","connectionId":4}}
```

And just in case you are wondering where I got the rootCA.pem and mongodb.pem files, I just went through this tutorial : https://rajanmaharjan.medium.com/secure-your-mongodb-connections-ssl-tls-92e2addb3c89

Comment: check server log

Comment: I tried looking at the syslog but there is no useful info as nothing happens when I enter the command above. Which logs are you talking about and how do I access them ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: OK sorry I will post my command in formatted text it's fixed

Comment: How does your mongod config file look like? Are you sure, you require client certificates? How did you create the user?

Comment: Yes I am sure I need a certificate for TLS/SSL encryption on mongodb. I have added my mongod.conf file and the method I used to create a user

Comment: Have a look at the logfile, /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: I've added the error from the logs to the post. But how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your config file and `createUser` you use the TLS/SSL certificate only to encrypt the connection. In this case skip `--tlsCertificateKeyFile mongodb.pem` option.

The MongoDB server provides the certificate (`mongodb.pem`), the client has to verify this certificate by using the CA `rootCA.pem`

If you like to use `--tlsCertificateKeyFile`, then you must specify the `CAFile` in `mongodb.conf`. Otherwise the MongoDB server cannot verify the certificate provided from the client:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls :
    mode : requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile : /home/youssef/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/rootCA.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true  # if you like to permit connections with and without certificate
```

Note, try `openssl verify -CAfile rootCA.pem mongodb.pem` in order to check if your certificate is working and valid.

Comment: I did exactly as you told me to I didn't mention --tlsCertificateKeyFile in my command and added net.tls.CAFile root to mongod.conf but I still got the same error. I also would like to add that when I enter "mongo" command I get : network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'